# Provoque element change in a foreach in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 loops,

I would like that for each iteration of fighters2, $fighter1 also advance 1 element. Is is posible to do it with foreach????

```
    foreach ($fighters1 as $fighter) {
        foreach ($fighters2 as $fighter2) {
         }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @juliatzin-del-toro, what do you mean with advance 1 element?
Thanks!

Comment: I want fighter to iterate once more ( if fighter was fighters1[0] I would like it to be fighters1[1]

Answer (score 0):

not sure if i understand the question correctly, but here is the answer to how i understood the question.
if your arrays are the same size you could do sth like this:

```
foreach($fighters1 as $index => $fighter) {
    $fighter2 = $fighters2[$index];
    //do what you need to do with $fighter and $fighter2
}
```

that is assuming both arrays are same size and have numeric indexes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `next()` might help you.

```
foreach ($fighters1 as $fighter) {
   $nextFighter1 = next($fighters1);
   foreach ($fighters2 as $fighter2) {
       //do whatever you need
   }
}
```

[next() reference](http://php.net/manual/es/function.next.php)

Bye!